How to differentiate or segregate the individual feature file karate gatling reports when we run multiple files at a time
To perform the performance testing am using karate gatling 1.4.1 with using scala class.
Scala class:
package Performance

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class Testing extends Simulation {

  val create = scenario("create").exec(karateFeature("classpath:Performance/Demo.feature"))
  val create1 = scenario("create1").exec(karateFeature("classpath:Performance/Demo1.feature"))
  val create2 = scenario("create2").exec(karateFeature("classpath:Performance/Demo2.feature"))

  setUp(
    create.inject(rampUsers(10) during (8 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
    create1.inject(rampUsers(6) during (10 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
    create2.inject(rampUsers(8) during (10 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
  )

}

When I ran this class using maven command, in a single gatling report it will show the results for all the 3 feature files which am running and there is no differentiation between those.
If I ran the 3 feature files at a time and wanted to see the performance for 3 files individually, how to achieve this?
For this I tried to add individual SetUp() for every feature file and some other alternatives I tried somehow nothing got worked, need the help to fix this.
Thanks.

I don't think this is supported. most teams seem to be doing fine with how it works. we encourage people to come forward and contribute code if needed.
